# How to access the superclass object from the subclases?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have been asked to write a program in java which has a class named 1.College(it has 'collegeName' and 'address' as its data members) 2.Department which inherits college(and has 'departmentName' and 'hodName' as its data members) 3. FaultyMember which inherits Department(it has 'facultyMember', 'facultyMemberQualification' and 'yearsOfExperience' as its data members).

I want user to enter the name of the college and its address. And then ask the user to input the no of departments in the college then the name of the each department and the corresponding HOD of the departments. Now, as the user inputs the name of the first department the program also asks the no of faculty members in each departments and takes input of the faculty member name, qualification,and years of experience.

The problem which I am facing is that in my qestion the super class 'Department' needs to access the subclass 'FacultyMember'.

How to solve the problem.

I have written the code so far as...

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood what inheritance means. A FacultyMember is not a Department, and a Department is not a College. Thus, FacultyMember should not be inheriting from Department, and Department should not be inheriting from College.

Comment: Inheritance is for an _is a_ relationship. You're looking for composition, which is a _has a_ relationship.

Comment: You should use has-a relationship instead of is-a.

Comment: But I have been asked to inherit 'College' class to 'Department' and 'Department' to 'Faculty'...

Answer (score 0):

Hi without going into the design semantic of your senario. 
Answer to the question is.

A parent class has know obligation to know about its child. Hence you can't access child class fields inside a parent.

About the design of the senario. 
Kindly read about "Has a" and "is a" relationship.

Comment: I know how to create an object of one class inside another. But, how to implement it?

Comment: You can create objects. But your question was     "the super class 'Department' needs to access the subclass 'FacultyMember    "  which is not possible.